# React router is not loading component on Redirect

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, react-router

I am trying to load a component on : `http://localhost:3001/api/posts/success`

my route tree looks like:

```
import SuccessMessage from './components/SuccessMessage';


<div>
      <Router>
        <Route component={Navbar} />
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
            <Route exact path="/api/posts/:city" component={ViewPost} />

            <Route exact path="/api/posts/item/:id" component={ItemDetails} />
                    <Route exact path="/api/posts/success" component={SuccessMessage} />
                    <Route exact path="/api/posts/termsofservice" component={termsOfService} />
            <Route exact path="/createpost" component={CreatePost} />

        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </div>
```

the module being exported

```
import React from 'react';
import { Jumbotron, Button  } from 'react-bootstrap';

const SuccessMessage = () => {
    return (
        <Jumbotron>
            <h1>Post Successfully Submitted!</h1>
            <p>
                Your post will be reviewed to ensure it does not violate our Terms Of Service, upon approval it will be
                displayed on the main page. Edit or Delete your post in your User Settings.
            </p>
            <p>
                <Button variant="primary" onClick={() => (window.location = `http://localhost:3001/api/posts`)}>
                    >Go To Listings
                </Button>
                {'  '}
                <Button variant="primary" onClick={() => (window.location = `http://localhost:3001/api/posts/termsofservice`)}>
                    Read Our T.O.S
                </Button>
            </p>
        </Jumbotron>
    );
};

export default SuccessMessage;
```

when I hit the page I only see the navbar.. [image]

EDIT: The solution is that when we have a wildroute :city it will block all the other routes, notice

```
<Route exact path="/api/posts/:city" component={ViewPost} />
```

Comment: there is no redirect and you have to return an element inside your JSX, i.e. `return (<></>)`

Comment: is it the only `Route` causing problems? Is `termsOfService` working?

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: The solution is that when we have a wildroute :city it will block all the other routes, notice

```
<Route exact path="/api/posts/:city" component={ViewPost} />
```

therefore, for wildroutes, ensure you make it distinct

```
<Route exact path="/api/posts/city/:city" component={ViewPost} />
```